# R graph colors are not correct ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a line graph and highlighted some points. Here is a toy example of the error I get:

```
library('ggplot2')
time <- as.POSIXct(c("2014-12-10 20:51:53.103","2014-12-10 20:56:54.204",
                     "2014-12-10 20:57:54.204"), tz= "GMT")
p <- c(49.32, 60,50)
s <- c("B","","S")
pointcolor <- c("green","","red")
share <- c(35,0,6)
pointsize <- c(10,10,10)
shapeType <- c(16,10,16)
bigDF <- data.frame(time=time, p=p, s=s, pointcolor=pointcolor, share=share,
                    pointsize=pointsize, shapeType=shapeType)
bigDF
ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_point( aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType), 
                  size = pointsize, color = pointcolor))
scale_color_manual(values = levels(as.factor(bigDF$pointcolor)))
scale_size_manual(values = levels(as.factor(bigDF$pointsize)))
```

when you run that you get a graph that looks like:
[image]

I am trying to color the first point green, the second point should be black and the 3rd point should be red. But you can see the 2nd point is red and the 3rd point is  blue not red.

I have some questions:

Why is second point red not black?

Why is the third point blue not red?

Why does the pointcolor legend show a red dot and no description?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use ggplot as if it's base graphics. In general, data sets don't have literal "color" columns, which is why the mapping of a column to "color" (`aes(color = column)`) is separated from the choice of colors to use (`scale_color_*()`).

You don't have any black points because of a syntax error. You're missing your `+` signs to add your `scale`s to the plot, so you actually use the default ggplot colors (red, green blue, for 3 levels) assigned to your `pointcolor` factor in default alphabetical order, first `""`, then `"green"`, then `"red"`.

Fixing that error by putting in the `+` isn't enough, since `""` isn't a color. I think you are asking for something like this:

```
bigDF$pointcolor = factor(ifelse(bigDF$pointcolor == "", "black", bigDF$pointcolor))
ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + geom_line() + 
geom_point( aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType), 
                size = pointsize,
                color = pointcolor)) +
scale_color_manual(values = levels(bigDF$pointcolor))
```

but what you *should* be doing is having a column in your data that is *meaningful*, then defining the scale for it in the scale functions, rather than trying to code your color scale into your data.

#### Meaningful columns:

By *meaningful* data columns, I mean the ones that are actually data. I'm not sure exactly what your data *is*, but I think your meaningful columns are `time`, `p`, `s`, and `share`.

You haven't specified, it looks like your colors are based on your variable `s`, and (a bigger guess) the shape is whether or not your variable `share` is 0 or not. This *should* be plotted like this:

```
dd <- data.frame(time=time, p=p, s=s, share=share)
ggplot(dd, aes(x = time, y = p)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(color = s, shape = share > 0), size = 10) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "green", "red")) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 10))
```

Notice that the data frame is simpler, no colors or shapes because *those aren't your data*. The `aes()` function takes care of mapping data to color and shape, and the `scale` functions determine what values the results take. And notice that the default legend labels are now useful!

This is the way ggplot is meant to be used. The data doesn't need extra columns to describe the graph, the code for the plot is both shorter and more clear, the labels on the legends are as good as the labels in the data frame.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can I ask what do you mean by meaningful? I have columns in my data for pointsize, pointcolor, shapetype. I am using them to display the size, color, shape etc. Aren't those the meaningful column you speak of? Also, Would you say that scale_color is necessary here because I want to specify the color to use?

Comment: See edits, added a new section. The `scale` functions override defaults, you can leave them out if you're happy with the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually specify that the black color is black instead of `""`. You can keep your DF as you built with `pointcolor <- c("green","black","red")`. This just simplifies the typing.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_point( aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType),size = pointsize, 
                  colour = c("green","black","red"))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green","black","red"))
```

Comment: Hi @ALEX - I made that change but when I re-run the first point is black and second point is green. It should be the opposite.   Also, The scale for pointcolor says black but the color is green and when it says green it is black. Any idea how to fix? thank you.